# Loading a UIViewController into a Container View programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is in the latest XCode, 11.3.  I've looked through the answers to similar questions, but some of the function names and parameters seem to have changed.

While working through a Udemy course, I'm trying to make a simple log in / sign up interface. In my first view controller I have a vertical stack view containing a label, a segmented control, and a container view. The segmented control can be either "Log In" or "Sign Up". I want to load the appropriate view controller when the segmented control changes.

[image: Top Level View Controller]

My LogInViewController has a vertical stack view with a text field for username, another for password, and a Log In button. My SignUpViewController has a vertical stack view with text fields for email address, username, password, and password confirmation followed by a Sign Up button.

My first view controller looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var logInSignUpControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet var customContainer: UIView!

    var logInVC: LogInViewController?
    var signUpVC: SignUpViewController?
    var activeVC = 0

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        initializeCustomControllers()
    }

    func initializeCustomControllers()
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        logInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInViewController") as? LogInViewController
        signUpVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") as? SignUpViewController

        logInVC?.willMove(toParent: self)
        logInVC?.view.frame = customContainer.bounds
        customContainer.addSubview(logInVC!.view)
        addChild(logInVC!)
        logInVC?.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
```

Unfortunately, this only shows the LogInViewController, not the label or segmented control.

[image: How It Looks]

I haven't been able to find a clear description of how to do this in the latest version of XCode and Swift, so I've pieced this together from various blog posts and Stackoverflow comments about older versions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `customContainer`  linked for in IB

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question, Sh_Khan.  The element in the main storyboard is a Container View, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: in storyboard there is an arrow which vc it points to ?

Comment: The first, default one containing the segmented control.

Comment: make sure this `@IBOutlet var customContainer: UIView!` is linked to the containerview and not to the vc's main view in storyboard

Comment: That was it!  Like all good bugs, I feel a bit foolish for not catching it myself.  Thank you -- if you add it as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure this `@IBOutlet var customContainer: UIView!` is linked to the containerview and not to the vc's main view in storyboard

Comment: My Log In and Sign Up views now appear correctly, but they don't get the focus in the simulator.  Do I need to make some explicit call to make them usable?

Comment: what focus no keyboard appears ?

Comment: add them inside `viewDidLoad` and in segment action toggle the `ishidden` for both

Comment: call `loginTexf.makeFirstResponder()` when you show loginView`

Comment: I'm confused (obviously).  The views appear, I just can't enter text in the text fields or get a response from clicking on the button in the simulator.  Calling becomeFirstResponder() on the first text field allows me to enter text there, but I can't click on the others, although I can tab to them.  The button is visible but can't be clicked.

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code :)

PS: `@IBAction func controlChanged(_ sender: Any)` is an IBAction for the "ValueChanged" Event

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var logInSignUpControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet var customContainer: UIView!

var logInVC: LogInViewController?
var signUpVC: SignUpViewController?
var activeVC = 0

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    initializeCustomControllers()
}

@IBAction func controlChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    changeVC()
}

func changeVC() {
    if activeVC == 0 {
        signUpVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        logInVC?.willMove(toParent: self)
        logInVC?.view.frame = customContainer.bounds
        customContainer.addSubview(logInVC!.view)
        addChild(logInVC!)
        logInVC?.didMove(toParent: self)
    } else {
        logInVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        signUpVC?.willMove(toParent: self)
        signUpVC?.view.frame = customContainer.bounds
        customContainer.addSubview(signUpVC!.view)
        addChild(signUpVC!)
        signUpVC?.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    activeVC = activeVC == 0 ? 1 : 0
}

func initializeCustomControllers()
{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    logInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInViewController") as? LogInViewController
    signUpVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") as? SignUpViewController
    changeVC()
}
```

}

Comment: Also make sure that "customContainer" is pointing to the correct view, because I think it is linked to the main view of the ViewController

Comment: You and Sh_Khan both figured that out quickly.  Thank you for the improved code.

Comment: the above code will keep adding many sub views as the user clicks so check whether the varaibles ar not nil

Comment: Are you referring to the customContainer.addSubview call, @Sh_Khan?

Comment: @Sh_Khan, this code removes the view from the superview before adding the other view, so it is safe to re-add it, it's better than adding both of them and keep on changing "isHidden"